# Load different views after rotation

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview, rotation, xib

I have a view controller which contains a ScrollView and an array of views on that. When i rotate the device a strange situation happens with the frames of my view. I googled and Stackoverflow'd, i need to use two different .xib files but i have no idea about how to do. Can any one share some opinion-or link to tutorial please?

My app is Web-Service application and the information comes from a web server. I tried to create two different .xib files and display them differently but it is too much coplicated(or comes so to me). Please, just a link or an idea wwill be great helper